# How to trigger if {} function after any change to var number in jQuery? rather than only firing on document ready

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am struggling to figure out how to to trigger an if function after a change to my var number in jQuery. The intention being to use the variable to add/remove html classes to different anchors. Currently, the function only works upon the document loading, responding to whichever placeholder number I put in.

Here is the js/jQuery:

```
//calls the url, which will have a number at end
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
//this isolates the number from the url
var str = pathname.replace("/Users/xxx/Desktop/CODING/WEB%20(HTML5%20&%20CSS)/JPF%20PORTFOLIO/CODE/", "");

$(document).ready(function() {
//var = 'numbaa' is a placeholder for the url number
var numbaa = 2;
// two buttons, one moves value up - other moves down (and loops after cap)
   $("#icona2").click(function() {
      if (numbaa >= 3) {
        numbaa = 1
        alert(numbaa);
      } else {
      numbaa++;
      alert(numbaa);
      }
   });
   $("#icona1").click(function() {
      if (numbaa <= 1) {
        numbaa = 3
        alert(numbaa);
     } else {
      numbaa--;
      alert(numbaa);
     }
   });

  //from the value, add a class to the correct html anchor
    if (numbaa == 1){
      $(".itemadd").removeClass("itemadd");
      $(".txtitem1").addClass("itemadd");
    }else{};
    if (numbaa == 2){
      $(".itemadd").removeClass("itemadd");
      $(".txtitem2").addClass("itemadd");
    }else{};

});
```

Cheers

Comment: What action would cause the variable to change? Create an event handler for that action and do your checking in that handler.

Comment: Apologies, but I am an absolute beginner.

the variable 'numbaa' is changing on the button clicks as evidenced by both the console and by alerts. The issue I have is a lack of understanding over how functions work beyond on "$(document).ready".

What does an event handler look like and where would I place it in order for it to be responsive to changes in the variable number that are occurring?

Comment: So put it in a function and call it

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you want to run in a function. Call it when the page loads. And call it in the button clicks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numbaa = 2;
   $("#icona2").click(function() {
      // your code
      changeDisplay();
   });
   $("#icona1").click(function() {
      // your code
      changeDisplay();
   });

   function changeDisplay () {
     if (numbaa == 1){
     }
   }
});
```

Now I would reduce all the repeated code and use data attributes. Basic idea is below.

```js
var numbaa = 1;

function changeDisplay() {
   console.log(numbaa);
   // your add remove class code here
}

$(".count").on("click", function () {
  var btn = $(this);
  var dir = Number(btn.data("dir"));
  numbaa+= dir;
  if (numbaa > 3) numbaa = 1;
  else if (numbaa < 1) numbaa = 3;
  changeDisplay();
});

changeDisplay();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="count" data-dir="-1">DOWN</button>
<button class="count" data-dir="1">UP</button>
```

Comment: Success! Thank you very much for explaining this all to me, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
$('.theNumberClass').change(function() {
console.log('hey, your number changed');
});
```